# Tallying sequences from a list

Tags: r, list, dplyr, plyr

I have a list of string arrays imported from json.

```
data = fromJSON("data.json")

> data
[[1]]
[1] "Finish"  "Accept"  "Request"

[[2]]
[1] "Finish"  "Accept"  "Request"

[[3]]
[1] "Finish"        "Accept"        "UnlockRequest"
[4] "Accept"        "Request"      

[[4]]
[1] "Finish"  "Accept"  "Request"

[[5]]
[1] "Finish"  "Accept"  "Request"
```

My goal is now to tally the list objects, similar to the `table()` function of data table, however `table(data)` returns an error:

Error in `table(data)` : all arguments must have the same length

What is the correct workaround here ?

The output should look something like:

```
c("Finish", "Accept", "Request") 4
c("Finish", "Accept", "UnlockRequest", "Accept", 
    "Request") 1
```

the data:

```
 list(c("Finish", "Accept", "Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", 
"Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", "UnlockRequest", "Accept", 
"Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", "Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", 
"Request"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note sure if this is "correct", but here's one way. Basically turn it into a `data_frame` with one list column, manipulate the list column (using `as.character`), and then count it:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(l1) %>%
    mutate(char = as.character(l1)) %>%
    count(char)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  char                                                                        n
  <chr>                                                                   <int>
1 "c(\"Finish\", \"Accept\", \"Request\")"                                    4
2 "c(\"Finish\", \"Accept\", \"UnlockRequest\", \"Accept\", \"Request\")"     1
```

Another way would be to `paste` the text together, run `table`, and then use `strsplit`.

```
table(sapply(l1, paste, collapse = ',')) %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>%
    mutate(list_col = strsplit(Var1, ','))

Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Var1                                           n list_col 
  <chr>                                      <int> <list>   
1 Finish,Accept,Request                          4 <chr [3]>
2 Finish,Accept,UnlockRequest,Accept,Request     1 <chr [5]>
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error in count(., char) : object 'char' not found`

Comment: Do you have your list stored as `l1` or did you edit that part to reflect what's in your enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `as.character()` on your list, then tabulate the result.

```
as.data.frame(table(as.character(x)))
#                                                          Var1 Freq
# 1                            c("Finish", "Accept", "Request")    4
# 2 c("Finish", "Accept", "UnlockRequest", "Accept", "Request")    1
```

Data:

```
x <- list(c("Finish", "Accept", "Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", 
"Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", "UnlockRequest", "Accept", 
"Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", "Request"), c("Finish", "Accept", 
"Request"))
```